# Returning a String instead of looping print statement

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and I'm curious as to how to store values in a string and then return it. In the example below 2 numbers are picked, for example 2 and 8, and the program should return 2x1 =2, 2x2=4,..... all the way up to 2x8 =16. This can obviously be done by constantly looping a print statement as I have done, but how would I be able to store all the values in a String and then return the string.

```
function showMultiples (num, numMultiples)
{
for (i = 1; i < numMultiples; i++)
  {
    var result = num*i;
    console.log(num + " x " + i + " = " + result+ "\n"); 
  }
}
console.log('showMultiples(2,8) returns: ' + showMultiples(2,8));
console.log('showMultiples(3,2) returns: ' + showMultiples(3,2));
console.log('showMultiples(5,4) returns: ' + showMultiples(5,4));
```

Comment: As you are new to javascript, I hava tip for you: **Always use `var`**. If you declare a variable by writing something like `i = 1;`, the variable is saved in the global scope which you usually don't want.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that because I declared it in a function it would be a local variable. Now I know.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showMultiples(num, numMultiples) {
  // the accumulator (should be initialized to empty string)
  var str = "";
  for (i = 1; i < numMultiples; i++) {
    var result = num * i;
    // use += to append to str instead of overriding it
    str += num + " x " + i + " = " + result + "\n";
  }
  // return the result str
  return str;
}

var mulOf5 = showMultiples(5, 10);

console.log("multiples of 5 are:\n" + mulOf5);
```

The operator `+=` add the a value (right operand) to the previous value of the left operand and stores the result in the later. So these two lines are the same:

```
str = str + someValue;
str += someValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use string concatenation:

```
var finalResult = ""
...in your loop...
finalResult += num + " x " + i + " = " + result+ "\n"
```

Often you can also just collect the results in an array and use `join` to append them.

```
var lines = [];
... in your loop:
lines.push(num + " x " + i + " = " + result);
... afterwards
console.log(lines.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you wanted to use ES6 syntax using backticks for a template string, you can use the below. This is a little more readable and is exactly where it is useful (so long as you can use ES6 wherever you're using JavaScript).

```js
function showMultiples(num, numMultiples){
  let result = '';

  for(let i = 1; i < numMultiples; i++){
    result += `${num} x ${i} = ${i * num}\n`;
  };

  return result;
}

console.log(showMultiples(2,8));
```